# Hadoop 2.2.0 installation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop. i want to install hadoop 2.2.0 version. as MRv1 and MRv2 are very much diffrent. is there any step wise documentation for installation of hadoop 2.2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link for [hadoop 0.23.9 installation](http://learninghadoopblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/hadoop-0-23-9-single-node-setup-on-ubuntu-13-04/) on ubuntu. But is same for hadoop 2.2.0. try it